# Add js conditional in theme.info

Tags: theming

Add JS in themes.info

scripts[] = js/style.js

scripts[] = js/custom.js

scripts[] = js/common.js

But I Want to custom.js and common.js Add Conditionally

custom.js add only Front Page

And

custom.js add all page escape Front Page.

I want to add js only From themes.info File.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using this

```
function yourtheme_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  if(drupal_is_front_page()) {
    drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('theme', 'yourtheme') . '/js/your-front-script.js');
  }
}
```

Comment: yourtheme_preprocess_page function use in template.php but want to only in themes.info

Comment: You can't @RiturajKumar, .info files don't contain logic just config